# 502 gateway - ajax response - django

Tags: python, ajax, django, uwsgi

I generate Image with Celery task in this code. this is the part of an ajax view function.

```
task_result = generate_result_image.apply((answer, combi.id, lang))
if task_result.state == "SUCCESS":
     response['ok'] = 'yes'
     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

this is working locally perfectly, but in prod server, i am getting 502 bad gateway. this is the browser console msg:

[image]

what am I doing wrong? this is really mysterious..

this is the uwsgi log, the line where the cursor stands is the call I am doing. I seems, the worker is dying right after my call... no idea why..

[image]

Comment: This is probably about your nginx + uwsgi configuration (if I remember correctly your setup).

Comment: @alecxe hey alex, do I need setup something else in nginx+uwsgi conf for ajax ?

Comment: Not sure it would help, but quick google search points to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529288/nginx-django-502-bad-gateway, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319896/502-bad-gateway-django, http://serverfault.com/questions/504901/nginx-502-bad-gateway-runing-django-in-uwsgi.

Comment: @alecxe you are right, i think, please see my update, i posted the screenshot from uwsgi logs

Comment: What a nice set of harakiris.

Comment: @alecxe anything wrong with them? :(

Answer (score 0):

problem solved - the bit was not my code, nor my settings but the remote server I was sending files to, to generate image. Many thanks to Alex for showing the right direction..